# Can anyone help me access an android head unit of a car using only the head units MAC addresses without turning on debugging or developer options

Tags: android

Hello good day everyone,

I’ll keep it simple.
So I own a Geely tugella 2023 and it has an so called android head unit but looks like something else. Its Chinese software. So I am trying to connect to it using an app called easy fire tools from the play store but could not it connected.

I am not very in tuned with these kind of things but any help would be great.

I think that you may need to access the developer options but that is only possible if the head unit is detached or disassembled from the car.

My HU (Head Unit) Info:​

System version: 0.2.9(61)
Hardware version: HW:V1.2
Firmware version: DL-5JA-PBAPO1A

Geely calls this software the GKUI.
The Chinese version of the car is called the Xingyue.
The car won't run any scripts or programs through the USB port at all unless you get into developer mode.

I am trying to side-load or install apps in the head unit using the IP address which I converted using the mac address it only provided.

Comment: Please follow [ask] to update your question. Shrink it shorter. The format of questions on StackOverflow has become quite strict in years, so any deviation would lead to downvotes